# Ubuntu 20.04: chromium core dumps after suspend

Tags: suspend, chromium

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04, Chromium is now useless after suspend. It core dumps with the following message:

```
[47879:48020:1007/114146.882994:ERROR:token_service_table.cc(140)] Failed to decrypt token for service AccountId-114914832852477799101
[47879:48020:1007/114146.883041:ERROR:token_service_table.cc(140)] Failed to decrypt token for service AccountId-117277107704874441175
Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Any hints as to why this is happening?

Comment: How did you install Chromium? If it's a snap, try finding a PPA and/or .deb and installing it that way.

Comment: It was automatically switched to snap as part of the upgrade process from 18.04. Reinstalling with apt is aliased to installing the snap; but I already tried uninstalling and reinstalling, and that didn't fix it.

Comment: I'd try installing it from a repo. http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/06/install-chromium-via-deb-ubuntu-20-04/ (I've not tested that, as I don't use 20.04.)

Comment: That works...I think. Now I'm getting these warnings, but it starts:

[57444:57444:1007/121013.369215:ERROR:vaapi_wrapper.cc(437)] vaInitialize failed (ignore if using Wayland desktop environment): unknown libva error
[57444:57444:1007/121013.455801:ERROR:vaapi_wrapper.cc(437)] vaInitialize failed (ignore if using Wayland desktop environment): unknown libva error

Comment: As long as it starts and works, I'd not worry about the errors. Do you only see them when  you start it in the terminal, or are they popping up somewhere else? (I've never seen those errors in my life, so don't know anything about them.)

Comment: Terminal only. I've never seen them before today, either.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the keystore (which decrypts your password) does not work. Obviously you've set up chromium with a password. Try to open chromium with

`chromium --password-store=basic`

If it works you should add this line into your desktop file at `/usr/share/applications/chromium.desktop`

This only works if you **DON'T** install it via snap